# Mean Element of a Finite Set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given a finite set $S = \{A_1,A_2,A_3...\}$ containing an arbitrary number of finite sets  such that for any $A_i{}\in{}S$ and $A_j{}\in{}S$, $| A_i{} | = | A_j{} |$, and given that for every $A_i{}\in{}S$, and for every $x\in{}A_i$, $x$ is a finite real number, could it ever be the case that for any $i$ and $j$, the mean values of $A_i$ and of $A_j$ coincide?

In other words, given two finite distinct sets of the same cardinality of real numbers, is it the case that the mean of the elements of these sets could ever be the same?

Comment: You lost me on the first line. What are elements of $S$? Are they sets of the form $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$ or simply symbols $a_i$

Comment: How do you define the mean value of $a_i$?

Comment: S is a set containing $a_1$, etc.  I've updated the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Mean value as in the sum of the elements divided by the cardinality of the set.

Comment: How do you sum the elements? You just said $x\in a_i$ implies that $x$ is finite. Finite what? A finite set? An integer? A real?

Comment: x is a finite, real number.

Comment: Right, so the elements of $S$ are sets, and the cardinality of $S$ is arbitrary (limited only in that it must be finite).

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. "could it ever be the case that the mean value of $a_i\in S$ could be equal to the mean value of another set $a_j\in S$ unless $i = j$?" Do you mean 1) Could it be that all the elements of $S$ have the same mean? Or 2) Could it be that distinct elements of $S$ have different mean?

Comment: @user2743479 "(limited only in that it must be finite)" Oh, so $S$ has to be finite?

Comment: Even tho it is answered and accepted, the question seems unclear. I have not read all the comments to fish for clarification.

Comment: The question seems relatively clear to me.

Comment: @Vladhagen It has been edit quite a bit since I last saw it. It seems relative clear to me too now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_i=\{i,-i\}$, for each $i=1,2,\ldots$.  Then each $a_i$ has mean $0$, and cardinality $2$.

And $S=\{a_1, a_2,\ldots\}=\{\{1,-1\},\{2,-2\},\{3,-3\},\ldots\}$.

Comment: An interesting and related question is if the elements of $a_i$ were restricted to the counting numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example would be the sets $A_1 = \{1,4\}$ and $A_2 = \{2,3\}$.

This covers the case of the counting numbers, and can be generalized to sets of any size comprised of real numbers.